# Bigquery create parent column from existing column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to create a column from another column in existing table using SQL. For example I have a ID column & I like to generate ParentID from it. ParentID should have values from ID column (but less values)

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Are you saying you just have "one" column called ID as your source and you want to generate parentid from it without knowing any other context of how records are related ? I feel some critical info is missing in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your understanding is correct. Basically, I am trying to generate sample hierarchies for testing my code. I do not have access to actual hierarchy (which is in production) so trying to produce sample data in dev.